# Do polynomials attain their infimum?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Assume $p\colon\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ is a polynomial such that $I:=\inf_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d} p(x)>-\infty$. Does there exist $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $p(x)=I$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes for $d=1$.

Not always for $d\geq 2$. The idea is to find two polynomials $q_i$, $i=1,2$ whose zero sets are disjoint but infinitely close at infinity, and set

$$
p(x):=q_1(x)^2+q_2(x)^2>0.
$$

For example, choose $d=2$, $q_1(x)=x_1$ (zero set: $x_2$-axis), $q_2(x)=(x_1x_2-1)$ (hyperbolic zero set approaching $x_2$-axis) and consider $x^{(n)}=(1/n,n)$.

Comment: I would say that the answer in the case when $d\geq 2$ depends on the polynomial $p$.

Comment: You're right. I edited my answer